# auto adjustable layout for all content

Tags: html, css, layout

I need to dev a very flexible layout for a cms so that the structure auto-adjusts regarding the content.
The basic layout min-with layout is suposed to obey 1024px wide and it works fine for the most os the cases, but as we're talking about a cms, the editor very often creates content or copy/paste it from word and the content makes the layout stretch out so that i can look nice.

This is a huge challenge for me and i don't know you can i create a dynamic layout that behaves nicely regardless the content.

I only can think in jquery to help on this, and compute the content size and try to reset it to the appropriate size, but that doesn't look very easy or clean solution to do it.

So i'm posting this question to "hear" from you and have some cool suggestions an ideas that i can try out.

I'm sure most of you hava faced similar challenges.

Here's the layout i'm working on
[alt text http://img132.imageshack.us/img132/7661/0606y.png](http://img132.imageshack.us/img132/7661/0606y.png)

Comment: Can you show us the source code (HTML/CSS) you already have?

Comment: hi. I'm using asp.net with master pages. I put here the dev url http://tinyurl.com/35wesnr so you can look into the html. Thanks in advance! I appreciated

Comment: take a look to this site: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-multi-column-liquid-layouts-em-and-pixel-widths

this guy has a very good solution for that what you want to do ;)

Comment: This looks very nice and close to what i  need. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A problem I've often had with layouts such as that is you want two columns to stretch to be the same size with dynamic content, but it doesn't always work. Here's a bit of Javascript that you might find useful in the future:

`document.getElementById("sidebar").style.height = document.getElementById("content").offsetHeight + "px";`

This assumes your height is in px (which it is 99% of the time), but it's useful for vertically stretching columns to match other columns.

Comment: Javascript to the rescue....it was what I thought...though i must admin the link Oden pointed out is very usefull and show some nice layout example done in the right way!